# Confirmation email is sent even when RequireConfirmedEmail is set to false in .Net Core Identiy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am implementing .Net Core Identity in my .net core 5.0 razor page application.

I have setup the identity to disable the email confirmation.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            {
                //Disable account confirmation.
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

From the UI perspective the user is logged in without email confirmation. So, the UI is working just fine.

**But the confirmation email is sent to the user anyway.**

Here's how I have registered the Email Service:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```

The reason for registering the email service is that I want to send the Reset Password email to the user.

I understand that the configuration says that the user does not have to be a confirmed user to login and do other activities.

**How do I configure email service in a way that it does not send the confirmation email but allow other emails to be sent?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to apply the scaffolder to add/generate the source code of registration, like below.

[image]

Check the `OnPostAsync` handler method defined in `RegisterModel` class, you can find the relevant code used to send email, then you can modify or comment out these block of code to achieve your requirement.

```
 await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

Comment: Yes, I discovered that just now. I was going to post the answer. Thanks.